# How to exclude multiple directories with rsync?

Tags: command-line, rsync

I am trying to backup my home directory using rsync, and I want to exclude some of the directories that contain junk.  I want to specifically exclude `/home/ben/.ccache` and `/home/ben/build`.  Unfortunately the documentation for rsync was information overload and didn't answer my question.  This is what I tried:

```
rsync -arv --exclude "/home/ben/.ccache:/home/ben/build" /home/ben /media/ben/thumbdrive/
```

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Just wanted to say that the flag `a` implies `r` already :) `-a, --archive               archive mode; equals -rlptgoD (no -H,-A,-X)`

Answer (score 329, accepted):

To exclude multiple directories you just use multiple `--exclude=path` switches. So the command from the question properly written is as follows:

```
rsync -arv --exclude=.ccache --exclude=build /home/ben /media/ben/thumbdrive/
```

**Note**: Use relative paths with exclude. The paths are relative to the source directory, here /home/ben.

Comment: An absolute path did *not* work for me (the directory specified was silently not excluded), whereas a path relative to the source directory worked correctly. Maybe I'm missing something, but I would be cautious about @FreeSoftwareServers' assertion that absolute paths always work.

Comment: FWIW, a little creative *diff* use can be helpful.  Assume you are adjusting the exclude flags from run to run in **nas_backup.sh**.  Assume also that are using `--dry-run`.  run:  `. nas_backup.sh > dryrun.5.txt`, adjust excludes, then run
`. nas_backup.sh > dryrun.6.txt`  then diff
`diff dryrun.5.txt dryrun.6.txt | less`   this will show you what was added/removed from scope between those 2 runs.

Comment: FYI: The option `-a` includes `-r` so `-ar` is redundant.

Comment: Contrary to what FreeSoftwareServers believes, the exclude path is relative to the source path, NOT /. So that comment is categorically false and will lead to failures if you follow it. The best strategy is to leave off the leading / in your excludes to avoid this type of mental error. If source is say, /home/me and if you exclude='/mydir/' this excludes the directory mydir in /home/me, that is, it excludes /home/me/mydir NOT /mydir/ at /. It's unfortunate I can't either downvote or edit that comment since it's technically wrong and will mislead.

Comment: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/01/rsync-exclude-files-and-folders/?utm_source=feedburner explains this quite clearly, note the section: 4. Exclude path is always relative (to the source path)

Comment: FYI for later travellers, it looks like the comment in question by @FreeSoftwareServer has been removed.  tl;dr:  use relative paths

Comment: If you're dumb then so am I and 179 other upvoters!

Comment: @Soren Bjornstad: you're right, it doesn't exclude the directory if you specify an absolute path. It has to be a relative path to the source directory for it to work.

Comment: Hm, is it possible at all to find this in the man page? That one can use the parameter several times?

Comment: Wow, I think this really trapped me and still puzzles me: it seems that you really need to put an equal sign `=` if you want to specify more than one exclude directory.

Answer (score 151):

When having multiple directories and/or files to exclude, make a text file and use the `--exclude-from` switch. Make a file called `exclude_me.txt` and in it list your exclusions.
Example (`/home/ben/exclude_me.txt`):

```
.ccache
build
.java
.gvfs
.xsession-errors
```

Then your rsync would look something like this:

```
rsync -arv --exclude-from='/home/ben/exclude_me.txt' /home/ben /media/ben/thumbdrive/
```

This is some information on filter rules that may help:

- `/dir/` means exclude the root folder `/dir`
- `/dir/*` means get the root folder `/dir` but not the contents
- `dir/` means exclude any folder anywhere where the name contains `dir/`
- Examples excluded: `/dir/, /usr/share/directory/, /var/spool/dir/
  /var/spool/lpd/cf` means skip files that start with `cf` within any folder
  within `/var/spool/lpd`

Also see the [filter rules](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) section on the man page.

Comment: It's important to note that *root folder* means the *root of the transfer* not the root directory.

Comment: `/var/spool/lpd/cf` excludes only the filename `cf`. To exclude all filenames starting with `cf`, you need to use `/var/spool/lpd/cf*`. And note: `/var/spool/lpd/cf` even excludes the dir name `cf` in this subdir.

Answer (score 134):

You can also exclude multiple paths within curly braces:

```
rsync -arv --exclude={.ccache,build} /home/ben /media/ben/thumbdrive/
```

Comment: this works nicely, just not under sh, only under bash, I found out "the hard way"

Comment: No space after the comma. Learnt that the hard way too 

Comment: And don't use '' like --exclude='.gvfs'

Comment: FWIW, I think curly braces work with ksh. For other shells, you could probably use something like: `IFS=$'\n'; rsync -arv $(printf '.ccache\nbuild\n' | sed 's/^/--exclude=/g') /home/ben /media/ben/thumbdrive/`. Or, you could just use multiple `--exclude` arguments, which you'd have to type manually.

Comment: The reason this works is because of "Brace Expansion", in case anyone wanted to look at the details.

Comment: It also works to have brace expansion in the middle of a path, like `--exclude=/folder/{one,two}/*`