# How to exclude a folder when using the mv command

Tags: command-line, bash, mv

I have this situation where I want to exclude a directory while using the `mv` command. I saw this example where the syntax would be `!(exclude_dir)`, but when I set up a scenario to test it I get results that I don't fully understand.

Now I have created three folders: `f1`,`f2` and `f3`. Now I use the command in this way:

```
mv -t f3/ !(f1) f2
```

This produces this error:

```
mv: cannot move 'f3' to a subdirectory of itself, 'f3/f3'
mv: cannot stat 'f2': No such file or directory
```

Now funny thing is the structure of the folder is now:

```
.
├── f1
└── f3
    └── f2

3 directories, 0 files
```

It does what I want but why the error messages. Obviously I am not using that command correctly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with `mv`, but is a `bash` feature, citing [`man bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/bash.1.html#contenttoc13):

> If the **extglob** shell option is enabled using the **shopt** builtin,
> several
> extended pattern matching operators are recognized.  In  the  following
> description, a pattern-list is a list of one or more patterns separated
> by a |.  Composite patterns may be formed using  one  or  more  of  the
> following sub-patterns:
>
> !(pattern-list)
> Matches anything except one of the given patterns

`!(f1)` matches `f2 f3` in your example, so effectively you're doing:

```bsh
mv -t f3/ f2 f3 f2
```

Then, it successfully moves `f2` to `f3`, raises the first error trying to move `f3` to itself, and raises the second error when trying to move `f2` to `f3` again because it was already moved and is no longer in the current directory.

To achieve your goal you should rather do:

```bsh
mv -t f3/ !(f[13]) # or !(f1|f3)
```

This expression matches everything except `f1` and `f3`.

This also works with `*`, `?` and `[…]`:

```bsh
$ ls
e1  e2  e3  f1  f2  f3
$ ls !(e*|?[12])
f3
```

Answer (score 4):

`!(f1)` is an extended *glob expression*, so (provided the `extglob` shell option is set) it expands to a **list** of (non)-matching files. In other words, if your directory originally contained `f1`, `f2`, `f3` then

```
mv -t f3/ !(f1) f2
```

expands as

```
mv -t f3/ f2 f3 f2
```

The first error should be obvious; the second is because it attempts to move `f2` twice - and fails the second time.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can also use `rsync`:

`rsync -arv --exclude=.ccache --exclude=build /home/ben /media/ben/thumbdrive/`

https://askubuntu.com/a/320459/585364

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a way to backup current files, it would be safer to split the move command into **copy & remove**. For example:

```
# Allow wildcard and hidden files search
shopt -s extglob dotglob

# Make a new directory (skip if exists)
mkdir -p BACKUP

# Copy all files to BACKUP (-a to keep attributes, -f to overwrite existing)
cp -af !(BACKUP) BACKUP/

# Remove all files except BACKUP (and hidden files starting with ".keep")
rm -rf !(BACKUP|.keep*)
```