# How to back up to an external USB drive all files with specified extensions?

Tags: 18.04, backup, file-format, usb-drive

Recommend software to locate and back up to an external USB drive all files with specified extensions (documents, pictures, videos, music, etc.) on my laptop a Toshiba Satellite S875-S7370 with Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 LTS? I will work but am too new to find what you suggest, install, use, etc.

Comment: Given you mentioned `xcopy` I'd suggest `rsync` (which has flexibility far beyond xcopy, however its rare for tools to do exactly the same.. and xcopy was very tied to fat/ntfs file systems where as `rsync` is *fs* agnostic meaning some options xcopy had won't make any sense).  Your question is very *opinion* orientated thus off-topic (https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/320458/how-to-exclude-multiple-directories-with-rsync & https://sites.google.com/site/rsync2u/home/rsync-tutorial/the-exclude-from-option & http://askubuntu.com/questions/40992/what-files-and-directories-can-be-excluded-from-a-backup-of-the-home-directory/40997#40997