Rsync exclude directories without filelist.txt
rsync -rv --include='index.js' --include='*/' \
                   --exclude='/node_modules/' \
                   --exclude='*' \
                   --prune-empty-dirs /www /testbackup -n

...some line in result..
www/proj-1/node_modules/xdg-basedir/index.js
www/proj-33/node_modules/somedir/index.js
...

rsync  version 3.1.2
I just want to get all index.js files only outside node_modules directory, any suggestion please without using filelist.txt

https://askubuntu.com/a/525513/1868352 still not work

You may be able to do this using rsync alone, however I'd find it easier to do with find + rsync:
find /www -type f -not -path '/www/*/node_modules/*' -name 'index.js' -print0 |
    rsync --dry-run --files-from=- --from0 -v / /testbackup

Remove --dry-run if you're happy with the result.
Note: you're using -r instead of the "standard" -a; from that I gather you don't want to turn on all the options normally turned on by -a. So this command won't either.
% tree /www
/www
├── proj-1
│   └── index.js
├── proj-10
│   └── node_modules
│       └── index.js
├── proj-2
│   └── index.js
├── proj-3
│   └── index.js
├── proj-4
│   └── index.js
├── proj-5
│   └── index.js
├── proj-6
│   └── node_modules
│       └── index.js
├── proj-7
│   └── node_modules
│       └── index.js
├── proj-8
│   └── node_modules
│       └── index.js
└── proj-9
    └── node_modules
        └── index.js

16 directories, 10 files
% find /www -type f -not -path '/www/*/node_modules/*' -name 'index.js' -print0 |
    rsync --dry-run --files-from=- --from0 -v / target
building file list ... done
www/
www/proj-1/
www/proj-1/index.js
www/proj-2/
www/proj-2/index.js
www/proj-3/
www/proj-3/index.js
www/proj-4/
www/proj-4/index.js
www/proj-5/
www/proj-5/index.js

sent 292 bytes  received 49 bytes  682,00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0,00 (DRY RUN)


with "-a" or "-r" get same result in my machine. also I was worried it would take more time on lots of files with added "find". it's works, thank you. may you suggest me how to add more include file contain string and exclude some dir start with "/." ,  I've tried with {'index.js','.js','.json'} but not luck

@SandriDianan The -a option doesn't to the same as -r, it includes, among other options, also -r. But it does more things (which you usually want by the way). See man rsync. The files you wish to add should be searched only outside node_modules like index.js? Ot should they be searched everywhere in www (I guess not)? With "exclude some dir start with "."" do you mean you want to exclude all hidden directories? Or only some? If only some, which should be excluded?

@SandriDianan Also yes, technically find adds some overhead. But I suppose rsync would be relieved from some work as well (as I guess in that case the files will be indexed from the disk only when find is running, although I'm not familiar with rsync's inner workings).

I want to do backup all  .js , .json files outside directory node_modules and hidden directories.  if after run this I find some .json / .js files that I need to exclude too, then I can add more specific directories outside node_modules and hidden directories

@SandriDianan Try replacing the find command with find /www -type f \( -not -path '/www/*/node_modules/*' -a -not -path '/www/*/.*/*' \) \( -name '*.js' -o -name '*.json' \) -print0

Wow, Im very happy, works for me. thank you very very much. +1, I'll research whats -a and -o means

@SandriDianan You can't actually +1 (vote on) answers yet :D you need more reputation for that. But you can accept the answer if you feel like it was helpful, which will grant me some reputation and, most importantly, tell others that the answer worked for you. You're welcome!
